# How to override the included function made from im_livechat.js where the function is also overriden from im_chat.js? using Odoo 8

Tags: javascript, odoo, odoo-8

How to override the included function made from im_livechat.js where the function is also overriden from im_chat.js?

Ex.

**im_chat.js**

```
im_chat.Conversation = openerp.Widget.extend({
   update_fold_state: function(state){
      return new openerp.Model("im_chat.session").call("update_state", [], {"uuid" : this.get("session").uuid, "state" : state});
   },
})
```

**im_livechat.js**

```
openerp.im_chat.Conversation.include({
    update_fold_state: function(state){
        if(state === 'closed'){
            this.destroy();
        }else{
            if(state === 'open'){
                this.show();
            }else{
                if(this.shown){
                    state = 'fold';
                    this.hide();
                }else{
                    state = 'open';
                    this.show();
                }
            }
        }
        var session = this.get('session');
        session.state = state;
        this.set('session', session);
        openerp.set_cookie(im_livechat.COOKIE_NAME, JSON.stringify(session), 60*60);
     },
});
```

**myjavascript.js**

```
openerp.im_livechat.Conversation.inlcude({
    update_fold_state: function(state){
        alert("Hello World");
    },
})
```

**My Goal:**

Instead of calling the **update_fold_state** function from im_livechat.js, i want to trigger **update_fold_state** function from myjavascript.js

Answer (score 0):

In your **myjavascript.js**

Replace `openerp.im_livechat.Conversation` with `openerp.im_chat.Conversation`

```
openerp.im_chat.Conversation.inlcude({
    update_fold_state: function(state){
        alert("Hello World");
    },

})
```

Comment: Hi @KbiR, I already try that but odoo still calling the function from im_livechat.js.

I want to manipulate the code from im_livechat.js . i wan't to add something in that code. but in my own file.